How to set up multiple predict tabs in R Shiny?
I am having an issue getting multiple predicts set up in the same R Shiny application. I have two different models, one for each work area I am working with (TRN, STR) that I want to have separate predicts set up for that reference their respective models. I am not quite sure how to have separate inputs for the two different tabs for the separate models.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#R Shiny ui
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  #Dashboard title
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Run Rate Prediction Model', titleWidth = 290),
  
  #Sidebar layout
  dashboardSidebar(width = 290,
                   sidebarMenu(menuItem("Plots", tabName = "plots", icon = icon('poll')),
                               menuItem("Turner Predictions", tabName = "TRNpred", icon = icon('search')),
                               menuItem("Straightener Predictions", tabName = "STRpred", icon = icon('search')))),
  #Tabs layout
  dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.main-header .logo {font-weight: bold;}'))),
                #Plots tab content
                tabItems(tabItem('plots', 
                                 #Histogram filter
                                 box(status = 'primary', title = 'Filter for the histogram plot',
                                     selectInput('num', "Numerical variables:", c('Temperature', 'Feeling temperature', 'Humidity', 'Wind speed', 'Casual', 'New', 'Total')),
                                     footer = 'Histogram plot for numerical variables'),
                                 #Frecuency plot filter
                                 box(status = 'primary', title = 'Filter for the frequency plot',
                                     selectInput('cat', 'Categorical variables:', c('Season', 'Year', 'Month', 'Hour', 'Holiday', 'Weekday', 'Working day', 'Weather')),
                                     footer = 'Frequency plot for categorical variables'),
                                 #Boxes to display the plots
                                 box(plotOutput('histPlot')),
                                 box(plotOutput('freqPlot'))),
                         #Dashboard tab content
                         tabItem('TRNpred',
                                 #Filters for categorical variables
                                 box(title = 'Categorical variables', 
                                     status = 'primary', width = 12, 
                                     splitLayout(
                                       tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible;}"))),
                                       cellWidths = c('0%', '40%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '8%'),
                                       selectInput( 'p_workcenter', 'Workcenter', levels(as.factor(TRNtestShiny$Workcenter))),
                                       
                                       div(),
                                       selectInput( 'p_grade', 'Grade', levels(as.factor(TRNtestShiny$Grade))))),
                                 #Filters for numeric variables
                                 box(title = 'Numerical variables',
                                     status = 'primary', width = 12,
                                     splitLayout(cellWidths = c('40%', '4%','40%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
                                                 numericInput( 'p_diameter', 'Diameter', 0),
                                                 div(),
                                                 numericInput( 'p_length', 'Length', 0),
                                     )),
                                 #Box to display the prediction results
                                 box(title = 'Prediction result',
                                     status = 'success', 
                                     solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                     width = 4, height = 260,
                                     div(h5('Run Rate Prediction:')),
                                     verbatimTextOutput("value", placeholder = TRUE),
                                     div(h5('Run Rate Range:')),
                                     verbatimTextOutput("range", placeholder = TRUE),
                                     actionButton('cal','Calculate', icon = icon('calculator'))),
                                 #Box to display information about the model
                                 box(title = 'Model explanation',
                                     status = 'success', 
                                     width = 8, height = 260,
                                     helpText('This model is used to predict the run rate in lbs/hr of a new product number.'),
                                     helpText(''),
                                     helpText(sprintf('', round(TRNRSS_Predictions, digits = 0), round(TRNRSS_Predictions, digits = 0))))),
                         #Prediction tab content
                         tabItem('STRpred',
                                 #Filters for categorical variables
                                 box(title = 'Categorical variables', 
                                     status = 'primary', width = 12, 
                                     splitLayout(
                                       tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible;}"))),
                                       cellWidths = c('0%', '40%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '8%'),
                                       selectInput( 'p_workcenter', 'Workcenter', c('STRAIGHTENER 1 ', 'STRAIGHTENER 2 ', 'STRAIGHTENER 3 ')),
                                       
                                       div(),
                                       selectInput( 'p_grade', 'Grade', levels(as.factor(STRtest$Grade))))),
                                 #Filters for numeric variables
                                 box(title = 'Numerical variables',
                                     status = 'primary', width = 12,
                                     splitLayout(cellWidths = c('40%', '4%','40%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
                                                 numericInput( 'p_diameter', 'Diameter', 0),
                                                 div(),
                                                 numericInput( 'p_length', 'Length', 0),
                                     )),
                                 #Box to display the prediction results
                                 box(title = 'Prediction result',
                                     status = 'success', 
                                     solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                     width = 4, height = 260,
                                     div(h5('Run Rate Prediction:')),
                                     verbatimTextOutput("value", placeholder = TRUE),
                                     div(h5('Run Rate Range:')),
                                     verbatimTextOutput("range", placeholder = TRUE),
                                     actionButton('cal','Calculate', icon = icon('calculator'))),
                                 #Box to display information about the model
                                 box(title = 'Model explanation',
                                     status = 'success', 
                                     width = 8, height = 260,
                                     helpText('This model is used to predict the run rate in lbs/hr of a new product number.'),
                                     helpText(''),
                                     helpText(sprintf('', round(STRRSS_Predictions, digits = 0), round(STRRSS_Predictions, digits = 0)))))
                )
  )
)

# R Shiny server
server <- shinyServer(function(input,TRNinput,output,TRNoutput) {
  
  #Prediction model
  #React value when using the action button
  a <- reactiveValues(result = NULL)
  # a_trn <- reactiveValues(result = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$cal, {
    #Copy of the test data without the dependent variable
    test_pred <-select(STRtestShiny,Workcenter,Grade,Length,Diameter)
    
    #Dataframe for the single prediction
    values = data.frame(Workcenter = input$p_workcenter, 
                        Length = input$p_length,
                        Grade = input$p_grade,
                        Diameter = input$p_diameter)
    
    #Include the values into the new data
    test_pred <- rbind(test_pred,values)
    
    #Single preiction using the randomforest model
    a$result <-  round(predict(STRModelValidate, 
                               newdata = test_pred[nrow(test_pred),]), 
                       digits = 0)
  })
  
  #OBSERVE EVENT TURNER
  observeEvent(TRNinput$cal, {
    #Copy of the test data without the dependent variable
    test_pred_trn <-select(TRNtestShiny,Workcenter,Grade,Length,Diameter)
    #test_pred$Workcenter<- str_replace(test_pred$Workcenter, "STRAIGHTENER 1 ", "STRAIGHTENER 1 LOAD")
    #test_pred$Workcenter<- str_replace(test_pred$Workcenter, "STRAIGHTENER 2 ", "STRAIGHTENER 2 LOAD")
    #test_pred$Workcenter<- str_replace(test_pred$Workcenter, "STRAIGHTENER 3 ", "STRAIGHTENER 3 LOAD")

    #Dataframe for the single prediction
    values_trn = data.frame(Workcenter = TRNinput$p_workcenter,
                        Length = TRNinput$p_length,
                        Grade = TRNinput$p_grade,
                        Diameter = TRNinput$p_diameter)

    #Include the values into the new data
    test_pred <- rbind(test_pred_trn,values_trn)

    #Single preiction using the randomforest model
    a_trn$result <-  round(predict(TRNModelValidate,
                               newdata = test_pred_trn[nrow(test_pred_trn),]),
                       digits = 0)
  })
  
  
  
  
  output$value <- renderText({
    #Display the prediction value
    paste(a$result)
  })
  
  TRNoutput$value <- renderText({
    #Display the prediction value
    paste(a_trn$result)
  })

  output$range <- renderText({
    #Display the range of prediction value using the MAE value
    input$cal
    isolate(sprintf('(%s) - (%s)', 
                    round(a$result - STRRSS_Predictions, digits = 0),
                    round(a$result + STRRSS_Predictions, digits = 0)))
  })
  
  TRNoutput$range <- renderText({
    #Display the range of prediction value using the MAE value
    TRNinput$cal
    isolate(sprintf('(%s) - (%s)',
                    round(a_trn$result - TRNRSS_Predictions, digits = 0),
                    round(a_trn$result + TRNRSS_Predictions, digits = 0)))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)

I attempted this code above and the error I received was related to the new input/output variables not having default values. I set them up no different to the first set so I was unsure how to tackle this problem.

Without the UI code, there is no way forward. Include the UI code so that others can have a complete perspective of the problem.

Apologies, I have added the UI code as well

This is not an MRE.  If you want someone to help you, please include TRNtestShiny and other objects used in this code.  A sample should be sufficient.

Sounds good I will remake this request
